# How to find the first instance of more than 1 character(s) in a string

Tags: c#, string

I am looking to see if there is a better way to figure out if which of two characters appears first in a string.

my current code for this is

```
string UserInput = Console.Readline;
char FirstFound;

if (UserInput.IndexOf('+') > UserInput.IndexOf('-') )
{
    FirstFound = '+';
}
else
{
    FirstFound = '-';
}
```

Is there a method that allows more than 1 input so can simplify this? Or anything else to make this shorter?

Comment: Shorten than this, not. But if you have more characters you can loop char by char

Comment: By "more than 1 input", do you mean you have more than one `UserInput`?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi no, I was asking if there is any way to find the index of the first instance of either 2 or more items in a string.

Answer (score 5):

You can shorten it a little bit by understanding the code effectively has the `-` character as the default value, because it's the result of the `else` block. With that in mind, we can do this to remove the `else` block:

```
string UserInput = Console.Readline();
char FirstFound = '-';

if (UserInput.IndexOf('+') > UserInput.IndexOf('-') )
{
    FirstFound = '+';
}
```

We could also do this, which is not shorter but will perform better:

```
string UserInput = Console.ReadLine();
char FirstFound;
foreach(char c in UserInput)
{
    if (c == '+' || c == '-')
    {
        FirstFound = c;
        break;
    }
}
```

Which we can shorten to use the linq `FirstOrDefault()` method:

```
string UserInput = Console.ReadLine();
char FirstFound = UserInput.FirstOrDefault(c => "-+".Contains(c));
```

If you want to able to expand this to allow more than two search targets, you can add the targets to the string like so, with no additional lines of code:

```
string UserInput = Console.ReadLine();
char FirstFound = UserInput.FirstOrDefault(c => "-+*/x÷".Contains(c));
```

Comment: Alternate version: `char FirstFound = UserInput.FirstOrDefault(c => "-+".Contains(c));`

Comment: Ooh, I like that. Mind if I steal it here?

Comment: Go for it sir! I put it as a comment in your answer.  ;)